# Play Framework 2.4.x execute a save operation in a callback function

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm a newbie using play framework and I need some help because I cannot find the reason why the code is not updating the address stored in the database.

I can see the log indicating success but I don't see the data change reflected; I'm not sure if it's something wrong with the code or I need to pass a context.

This sample code should store in the database and then we get success communication with the third party update some fields asynchronously.

Thanks in advance

```
public Result addUserAddress(final String userId) throws Exception {
    Address newAddress = AddressFrom.get();
    Address ua = new Address(user, 
    ThirdPartyApplication.findThirdPartyApplicationById(1));
    ua.save();

    Promise<Optional<Person>> promise = 
        restClient.findPersonByEmail(user.getEmail());
    promise.onRedeem(person -> {
        if (person.isPresent()) {
            restClient.addAddress(person.get().id, ua).onRedeem(address -> {
                ua.thirdPartyAddressId = String.valueOf(address.id);
                ua.thirdPartyUserId = String.valueOf(address.customerId);
                ua.save();

                Logger.info("Sync success.");
            });
        }
    });

    ObjectNode resultNode = Json.newObject();
    resultNode.set("address", Json.toJson(ua));
    return new Dummy(resultNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do async calls to the `restClient`, so you need to return promise if you want the action to reflect the result of the call and be async.

In the current code `ObjectNode resultNode = Json.newObject(); ..` will be run before the code that you put in the `onRedeem` function. i.e. `a.thirdPartyAddressId = String.valueOf(address.id);`.

To fix it you must chain async calls and create your `Dummy` object as the last element of the chain.

`Chaining` is all about to use `map` and `flatMap` opposite to `onRedeem`.

You need [to change the return type](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaAsync) to `Promise<Result>` and return your `Dummy` object in the place where you log now. You need also conver `onRedeem` to `map` and `flatMap`

I would advise you [to migrate to Play 2.6 and use](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaAsync#Creating-non-blocking-actions) `CompletionStage` instead of `Promise`.

Next code is just a draft, I did not check it because I do not have all that 
 classes, so use it just as a narrative:

```
public Promise<Result> addUserAddress(final String userId) throws Exception {
    Address newAddress = AddressFrom.get();
    Address ua = new Address(user, 
    ThirdPartyApplication.findThirdPartyApplicationById(1));
    ua.save();

    Promise<Optional<Person>> promise = restClient.findPersonByEmail(user.getEmail());

    return promise.flatMap(person -> {
        if (person.isPresent()) {
            return restClient.addAddress(person.get().id, ua).map(address -> {
                ua.thirdPartyAddressId = String.valueOf(address.id);
                ua.thirdPartyUserId = String.valueOf(address.customerId);
                ua.save();

                Logger.info("Sync success.");

                ObjectNode resultNode = Json.newObject();
                resultNode.set("address", Json.toJson(ua));
                return new Dummy(resultNode);
                //return ok("Dummy test");
            });
        }
    });


}
```